# Sort By Post title regardless of category in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Hello I need help in sorting list of post by title in wordpress regardless of the category name, Below is my initial code which sorts ascending but still consider the sorting of categories. I need a sorting code that will only sort the title in ascending order and disregard sorting its category.

```
        $args=array(

        'showposts'=> 7,

        'category__not_in' => array(20,8,11,3,4,5,6,1), //excluded category IDs

        'order'    => 'ASC'

    );

    query_posts($args);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
'orderby' => 'title'
```

to `$args`.  `order` only specifies the sort order.  It doesn't tell WordPress which field to sort.  See [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) for more detail.